# Can "npm run build" only be run from the folder that contains the package.json file?

Tags: npm, command-line, package.json

When running `npm run build` from the command line, can it only be used in the folder that contains the package.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes because `npm build` is an internal command and `npm build [<package-folder>]` So, the folder containing a `package.json` file in its root.And as per [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build).

> This is the plumbing command called by `npm link` and `npm install`. It should generally not be called directly.

From [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),we can say that the **env** script is a special built-in command that can be used to list environment variables that will be available to the script at runtime. If an “env” command is defined in your package, it will take precedence over the built-in.

In addition to the shell’s pre-existing PATH, `npm run` adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts. Any binaries provided by locally-installed dependencies can be used without the node_modules/.bin prefix. For example, if there is a `devDependency` on tap in your package